# Совершить звонок при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: xcode

Как в `xcode` сделать так чтобы, при нажатии на кнопку или текст совершался звонок - вызов на телефон?

Answer (score 2):

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed 
{
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12345678"];
     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) { // проверяем возможно ли сделать вызов, вдруг это iPod
         [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url]; // звоним
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Не хочу Вас огорчать.. но Xcode не умеет звонить :(

Comment: Он что даже экран набора не покажет?

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *phoneNumber = [@"tel://" stringByAppendingString:mobileNumber];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:phoneNumber]];
```